# Image upload crashes the mobile chrome browser.

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, mobile

I have a website with image uploading handled by javascript (Js doing the actual submitting of the form with multipart file upload). However, While checking across the browsers it seems to crash only on mobile chrome. Any one with any hint on why this behaviour occurs ? .

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment yet. Please share your code. Try to check your image well, as maybe the JavaScript you are using does not handle certain image types/sizes well on mobile Chrome?